# make object empty without mutating the state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react and redux, how to reset the object back to `{}` again?

```
export default function checkInReducer(state = initialState.user, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.GET_USER_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                ...action.user
              });

        case types.RESET_CHECKIN:
            //what should I do here? simply return {} ?

        default:
              return state; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your idea? Simple return `{}` should be fine. Is there any error/issue if you try that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said your `initialState.user` is an *empty object*:

```
export default function checkInReducer(state = initialState.user, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.GET_USER_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            ...action.user
          });

    case types.RESET_CHECKIN:
        return initialState.user 

    default:
          return state; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your reducers, you have set your default state to `initialState.user`.

```
checkInReducer(state = initialState.user, action) {
```

So,instead of setting/returning `{}` directly,you should return your initials state in this way.

```
case types.RESET_CHECKIN:
return initialState.user || {} //if initialState.user  is undefined then return {}
```

Comment: my initialState.user is {}

Comment: But you still uses`||` to handled accidental exception